# Google Assistant / Dialogflow: Cannot receive location thru mobile connection, but works on wifi

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-places-api, dialogflow-es

I am currently using the Google Places API. What I want to do is to receive the user's device lat / long coordinates and find nearby places of a certain type.

Somehow, this works with a wifi connection ie. I get back my list of nearby places and can display them on cards.

But when I disabled wifi and am connected to my 4G connection, I get the "[app name] isn't responding at the moment. Try again soon." message.

I checked my firebase function logs and I got back a response status of 200 with valid data, but at an incorrect location. Even so, shouldn't it display the data even at the wrong location?

Any idea on why this is happening? Google Maps location works fine for me ie. I can get my current location thru clicking on the appropriate button on Google Maps. I've also enabled Mobile Data for Google Maps and Assistant.

**EDIT:** I dug deeper into my logs. 
So turns out that on Google Cloud Platform, I found out that I'm getting a malformed response because of only one item in a Carousel.

> MalformedResponse at
>   expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].carousel_browse:
>   'carousel_browse' requires at least 2 items.

BUT this still doesn't solve the issue of wrong coordinates from the location itself.

This is what I got through a 4G connection (Firebase function logs):

```
 listPolicePost [ { geometry: { location: [Object], viewport: [Object]
 },
     icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png',
     id: '0e7b9a2a292b190e98e46bbdcb2c81ad6eb48f5e',
     name: 'Serangoon Garden Neighbourhood Police Post',
     photos: [ [Object] ],
     place_id: 'ChIJFzNrGAAX2jER2PowrtSXY_A',
     plus_code: 
      { compound_code: '9V78+9G Singapore',
        global_code: '6PH59V78+9G' },
     rating: 3.5,
     reference: 'CmRSAAAA-vgZQmvol1ZcY4srSlQGLRLIErqMGaZPJvgyySiigXxG_O9ysjoAZOjBwIxH99q6fAMnml69NOuogaYzpc84yYgGf6BaNJ7c0QhI4gwqxUUpeYPe9pW4EundAFi4IbTKEhAhCFSAhJeHTmmurQzf55eEGhTYyD6BAiFSZ35QMftDtdehqVhF0Q',
     scope: 'GOOGLE',
     types: [ 'police', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment' ],
     vicinity: '51 Serangoon Garden Way, Singapore' },   { geometry: { location: [Object], viewport: [Object] },
     icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png',
     id: '122baf85e424de14925665be49f5984cf367d61b',
     name: 'Serangoon Neighbourhood Police Centre',
     photos: [ [Object] ],
     place_id: 'ChIJo_ADBqcX2jERaelpKPuk7_0',
     plus_code: 
      { compound_code: '9V2C+R5 Singapore',
        global_code: '6PH59V2C+R5' },
     rating: 4.6,
     reference: 'CmRSAAAAt4STs5V8zT4-xRBKNU5EAqtLvHE1_CZr_Bk0WbNZqFdQztPT8HSeoRcw-Yksvz8TdiqzfQQGYXnAAqSJxNT6B9nAxhh0XlqkVLJh3Au0hCN8VrBhoSPujE8SBMfhjWPCEhCAgTBiiW9CWycfc9KneqEdGhT9BRJiiWfyx2KzqAJUyjAN3Snhpg',
     scope: 'GOOGLE',
     types: [ 'police', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment' ],
     vicinity: '50 Serangoon Avenue 2, #01-02' } ]
```

Results with WIFI at the same location:

```
 listPolicePost [ { geometry: { location: [Object], viewport: [Object]
 },
     icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png',
     id: '95c157891f885550b39dc74767a1ebc6fc426fa2',
     name: 'Alexandra Neighbourhood Police Post',
     photos: [ [Object] ],
     place_id: 'ChIJ42CR00Aa2jERvHTJPpayEZQ',
     plus_code: 
      { compound_code: '8Q2X+46 Singapore',
        global_code: '6PH58Q2X+46' },
     rating: 5,
     reference: 'CmRSAAAA6BBPfMynSJdnUhiFv3hGRmJxzSp4P6DGZ9_zAWX36EQEUXpxgmNgQNv1RYcH4B3d3Yxic5CaQK3Ec7UeY3dQW4Us92P8Y29yArsYfRuULrTOjdI4-GquWMzwB2wf6UubEhCHHitSm1_8jKBYWgPoU0vyGhRZUWXrfi9ShbA-dryqFABVCCwsmw',
     scope: 'GOOGLE',
     types: [ 'police', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment' ],
     vicinity: 'Blk 46 Tanglin Halt Rd, #01-328' },   { geometry: { location: [Object], viewport: [Object] },
     icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png',
     id: '8bdb0e2f344ec77efcc198ed410f0a06bc04fbbb',
     name: 'Commonwealth Neighbourhood Police Post',
     place_id: 'ChIJ39iOiz8a2jER6Wv2o-9yeGs',
     plus_code: 
      { compound_code: '8Q4X+HF Singapore',
        global_code: '6PH58Q4X+HF' },
     rating: 5,
     reference: 'CmRRAAAAprrqfgGSHVqj2xKP-TgSAagHxEIsWcak0WLiD_hqotMH-_lwWJg0HhlpW0MnxKZ5_yD3UWNkBT_0CjePxvt5Glu8PIC58AdmfDAmQ1fmPYxC64Au1WhwNuskwnS1a2M4EhCiJ7JzCXBGezyKo8HzhMwzGhRmp_Df8vfjWU_vasmr-QtXmWEi3Q',
     scope: 'GOOGLE',
     types: [ 'police', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment' ],
     vicinity: '111 Commonwealth Crescent, Singapore' },   { geometry: { location: [Object], viewport: [Object] },
     icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png',
     id: '34e78e46388c52c814cc5c0858b5f6ad3221511c',
     name: 'Buona Vista Police Post',
     photos: [ [Object] ],
     place_id: 'ChIJzeD5Imoa2jERih3LNGr2MSM',
     plus_code: 
      { compound_code: '8Q5V+P7 Singapore',
        global_code: '6PH58Q5V+P7' },
     rating: 2.8,
     reference: 'CmRRAAAAqDe2CLznGR81_LoV_7OnWIOne7g-zrP4h1U6ELKlc1zhVBMG15AmyxXJWJlZdys7ILMVUSj6Mv5_gDBsII72NMLHZ97gELkaUbrnKEBu0_o72VXwyJRLvuzcjCK8MqKyEhC6GmBSJYtpY4mSyNUeNk6WGhTwCRXaS5B5Xwx5zyrDE9xapnlRIg',
     scope: 'GOOGLE',
     types: [ 'police', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment' ],
     vicinity: 'block 13 Holland Dr #01-38/40' },   { geometry: { location: [Object], viewport: [Object] },
     icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png',
     id: '434ce574c05e43e70c33b6ba64d7f21c840b132f',
     name: 'Dover Neighbourhood Police Post',
     place_id: 'ChIJ73qudVwa2jERlggLteLz6nU',
     plus_code: 
      { compound_code: '8Q3J+GV Singapore',
        global_code: '6PH58Q3J+GV' },
     rating: 5,
     reference: 'CmRRAAAAdXD9jiCrSsH6oBqvxFviOGDBq_KOj08XfSR8mLSgTZhk8FCbt4UVqUUiWnvoLJv5jw5nytcTfellRW8Js_cRvQca_ToDtVbp6nQqaiq9RR408qaJm-9WOJuBZXTui9TQEhCyyQlxS4MRYvjh9dTD0qTmGhS95n1YPfpmR0BDcdYuWFQ6lYKG0A',
     scope: 'GOOGLE',
     types: [ 'police', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment' ],
     vicinity: 'Block 3, Dover Road, #01-368, 130003' },   { geometry: { location: [Object], viewport: [Object] },
     icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png',
     id: 'b2b998513d890ac0061b4b75380f26a3b7c4c81e',
     name: 'Special Operations Command',
     photos: [ [Object] ],
     place_id: 'ChIJH2LnQ8sb2jERA-RABTXay8c',
     plus_code: 
      { compound_code: '7RW2+76 Singapore',
        global_code: '6PH57RW2+76' },
     rating: 5,
     reference: 'CmRSAAAA8n7968a6h62bOQchkLcjdLGNlcCih7H3pQ1UmojLIXJOOD_RI8v5t3pZJlL0tZtTRBLpnIpgpXtEGu-48dPoELTPRu2Q_aHriAV4l2_YBf-tLR0RSNEQzOivTA7fPPxAEhDXhPRQs18Vfe-Ord4z-i0MGhS3eoucLyTZ504RQROrKrx18OEmGQ',
     scope: 'GOOGLE',
     types: [ 'police', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment' ],
     vicinity: 'Queensway, Singapore' } ]
```

Comment: maybe you need a [STUN](https://www.3cx.com/pbx/what-is-a-stun-server/) server.

Comment: @J4GD33P51NGH that feels like overkill for whatever im trying to do

Comment: To be clear - this is for the Google Assistant, correct? Can you update the question show the JSON you're sending back? Have you tested this on the simulator and do you have results for it?

Comment: @Prisoner I've updated. Turns out its not so much of a dialogflow or GA issue, but more so of why my location for 4G and wifi is different when i'm at the exact same spot.

Comment: Can you update it to show the code you're using to get the location from the Assistant? The results look like they're from the Places API, but they suggest there is a difference in their inputs and it isn't clear where the inputs come from.